# How to draw a line in menu item atctive

Tags: java, android, xml, android-menu

I want to put this little green line in the menu item that is active ... already has to create a shape and a custom style but no success ...

[image]

My **activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ordem"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="Home"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_auto_infracao"
            android:title="Payment Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_apreensao_deposito"
            android:title="Payment history" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_doacao"
            android:title="My card" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sincronia"
            android:title="Frinds" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use View to draw line.

```
<View
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: Where can I put the view?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is you can highlight the item by calling the following method to detect when to change the visibility and position the view:

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
```

Since you've mentioned you already have a shape and a custom style, put the view (here in this code below, `selectedItemBottomView`) inside the `NavigationView` in `activity_main` or the XML layout file where you've used the `activity_main_drawer` like this:

`activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/selectedItemBottomView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/green" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

On selected, change the visibility or position as per your requirement:

```
selectedItemBottomView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps.